# Send SMS via GSM modem with COM3 port using CMD or BAT

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have one GSM modem and I want to send SMS from my PC.
How to send AT commands from CMD or BAT file?
This modem using COM3 port.
I try SMSCaster, This is work fine but I need my own simple software.
How to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Send

```
echo ATDT>com3
```

Receive

```
copy com3 con
```

Here's a batch I wrote 15 years ago.

```
@echo off
echo Dialing Mum
echo ATDT 99999999 >com2
Echo.
Echo Press any key when Mum answers or you want to hang up.
pause
echo ATH >com2
```

Comment: I sent this but nothing returned.


C:\Users\Gio>echo ATDT>com3

C:\Users\Gio>